# Format XMLGregorianCalendar in java

Tags: java, date, xmlgregoriancalendar

i have a date String which looks just like this.

> 2017-12-06T17:39:00Z

What i would like to do is to convert this String to XMLGregorianCalendar but using the same format.

What i do at the moment is:

```
String choosenDate = 2017-12-06T17:39:00Z;

GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();

DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
TemporalAccessor accessor = timeFormatter.parse(dateChoisie);

Date date = Date.from(Instant.from(accessor));
c.setTime(date);
System.err.println("choosenDate: " + dateChoisie);
System.err.println("date : " + date);
XMLGregorianCalendar dateXMLGreg = null;
try
{
    dateXMLGreg = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    System.err.println("dateXMLGreg: " + dateXMLGreg);
}
catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e)
{
    messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().code("webservice.failure").build());
}
```

which gives me the following output:

> 10:47:45,957 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47) choosenDate:
>   2017-12-06T17:39:03Z
>
> 10:47:45,957 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47) date : Wed Dec 06
>   18:39:03 CET 2017
>
> 10:47:45,958 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47) dateXMLGreg:
>   2017-12-06T18:39:03.000+01:00

So how can i do so i have my XMLGregorianCalendar dateXMLGreg to look like:

> 2017-12-06T17:39:03Z

Comment: It’s not really the format that is different (this is always ISO 8601), it’s “just” the time zone offset from UTC. I understand that you will want to keep this the same, though.

Comment: Perhaps you need not bother with `XMLGregorianCalendar`. See the modern java.time classes now built into Java 8 and Java 9. The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC, and uses your string’s standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by default. `Instant.parse( "2017-12-06T17:39:00Z" )`

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks for pointing that out, you inspired an edit of [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47712834/5772882).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier than you think.

```
    String isoDateTime = "2017-12-06T17:39:00Z";
    XMLGregorianCalendar dateXMLGreg = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(isoDateTime);
    System.out.println(dateXMLGreg);
```

This prints

```
2017-12-06T17:39:00Z
```

`newXMLGregorianCalendar` has an overloaded version that accepts a string — *your* string — as argument. I trust you to add try/catch as in your question.

Edit: your `XMLGregorianCalendar` will have its milliseconds set to `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`. This needs to be so to avoid printing the milliseconds as part of the result from `toString()` (which gets implicitly called when you print the `XMLGregorianCalendar`).

**One more edit**: As Basil Bourque correctly said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711877/format-xmlgregoriancalendar-in-java#comment82414225_47711877), depending on what you need your `XMLGregorianCalendar` for, you may use and even benefit from using a class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead. For example:

```
    Instant dateInst = Instant.parse(isoDateTime);
    System.out.println(dateInst);
```

This gives the exact same output as above, `2017-12-06T17:39:00Z`. The `Instant` class will work only if the offset is always `Z`, which it probably is since this was what you asked to have back. The potential advantages of `java.time` include (1) the API is generally much nicer to work with (2) in case you need some further date-time operations, the modern API offers a wealth of them. If the offset may vary, you may experiment with `OffsetDateTime`, but this is a longer story that I will leave for some other question.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.

it is true that i had not thought about passing directly my date String in parameter. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```
    private XMLGregorianCalendar change(String dateStr) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;

    try {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date date = format.parse(dateStr);

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        System.out.println(xmlDate.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xmlDate;
}
```